# How to pass Multiple inheritable handle values to a child process...?

Tags: c, windows, process, systems-programming

In **windows process management**, if we want to pass the values of more than one **inheritable handle** to a child process, how should it be done.. ? I understand that we can use STARTUPINFO to pass one handle value, but how can I pass multiple handle values to a **child process**..?

Comment: If the command line isn't convenient for any reason, another option is to use the environment block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command line is a convenient place to pass all sorts of information.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how would you "marshal" the value before passing it on the command line? I mean do you convert it to some kind of text representation before passing it on or do you just give "raw bytes" as the command line knowing that you wrote the application on the other end at it'll know how to parse it (And you'll never have to worry people accessing the command line using ansi API functions or other horrific things)?

Comment: Since the command line is text-only, you have to [convert it to text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew I should have just been better at searching your blog (I have red ears now since I now recall having read the linked article). (PS: Never give in to the nitpickers)

Comment: Could you please explain how to convert that text back into a value.. As an example how can I do that with a file handler...?

Comment: You can see [the sample code I linked to](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/12/11/56043.aspx).